# Updating Kafka version over 3.2.3 crashes embeddedKafka unit tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

**Edit:** As suggested in the comments I have removed `<version>` from the spring artifacts and removed the tomcat 10 artifacts. I updated the pom.xml file accordingly but the same issue persists.

We are working on a Spring Voot application that uses Spring Kafka and embeddedKafka for some unit tests. Recently, kafka-clients requires 3.4.0 to overcome a vulnerability and I updated the version using `<kafka.version>3.4.0</kafka.version>` in the pom.xml file.

If I do this update and run the tests I get the following error:
`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kafka.common.KafkaException`
After some digging I understand that this usually comes from dependencies version mismatches. This fails all the unit tests that use `@EmbeddedKafka`.

I do not enforce any versions on the spring-kafka-test artifact and only use the kafka version property in pom.xml, so I let Spring Boot handle the dependencies matches.

This is my pom.xml file at the moment (updated)

```xml
<dependencies>
        <!--CF dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.pivotal.cfenv</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-cfenv-boot</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!--Spring dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
                    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>31.1-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.32</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.cloud.security.xsuaa</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsuaa-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${sap.cloud.security.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--ETD Commons-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.etd</groupId>
            <artifactId>etd_commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sap.etd.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>streaming-commons</artifactId>
            <version>1.21.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.retry</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-retry</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!--Utils-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--Testing-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jakarta.el</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-annotations-api</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.71</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.71</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-websocket</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.71</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-crypto</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-el</artifactId>
            <version>9.0.68</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I want to update to kafka 3.4.0, but after a couple of days of searching for answers and trying different artifact versioning, I am stuck.

I tried to only add the artifact for kafka-clients with the required version at first ,but that fails the tests, then after a couple of searches I saw that I should just add the artifacts with no versioning and handle the kafka version from the `kafka.version` property in pom.xml, but that didn't do the trick.

Comment: kafkaException is in the package org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException.

Comment: The term is unit test, not unitary test. As far as I can tell you seem to be handling too many dependency versions yourself which should be handled through Spring Boot. You also specify dependencies on Tomcat 10 (which can't work with Spring Boot 2.7), and Tomcat 9 (which can't work with Spring Boot 3). I'm not sure if that is the cause of the problem, but you should start with removing duplicate dependency declarations, and remove the `<version>` if they are managed by Spring Boot.

Comment: @KnockingHeads this is included in the kafka-clients artifact and when kafka is updated above 2.3.2 ClassNotFoundException is being thrown. 
This usually occurs when the JVM tries to load a particular class but does not find it in the classpath and in my case kafka-clients is present.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you for correcting me, I made the changes inside the pom.xml and re-run the unit tests but the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation for how to override the versions of all dependencies:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#update-deps

```
<kafka.version>3.4.0</kafka.version>
```

Note that the vulnerability is only in Kafka Connect so it's only an issue if your app is using both Spring for Apache Kafka and Kafka Connect.

**EDIT**

This works fine for me...

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.kafka.test.context.EmbeddedKafka;

@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(bootstrapServersProperty = "spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers")
class So75458160ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so75458160</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so75458160</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kafka.version>3.4.0</kafka.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

```
2023-02-16T11:01:23.097-05:00  INFO 18470 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig    : ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    auto.offset.reset = latest
    bootstrap.servers = [127.0.0.1:62159]
...
```

```
% ./mvnw dependency:tree
...
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.3.0:tree (default-cli) @ so75458160 ---
[INFO] com.example:so75458160:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.19.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.33:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:3.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.github.luben:zstd-jni:jar:1.5.2-1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.lz4:lz4-java:jar:1.8.0:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.1.8.4:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.10.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.2:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.0.2:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.7.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.4.8:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.1:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.23.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.12.22:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.12.22:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:4.8.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.0.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] \- org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:3.0.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.6.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper-jute:jar:3.6.3:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.yetus:audience-annotations:jar:0.5.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    |     \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.87.Final:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-metadata:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-server-common:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-raft:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.14.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.14.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.14.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.14.1:test
[INFO]    |  \- com.yammer.metrics:metrics-core:jar:2.2.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams-test-utils:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-streams:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |     \- org.rocksdb:rocksdbjni:jar:7.1.2:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-library:jar:2.13.10:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-group-coordinator:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.apache.kafka:kafka-storage:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- org.apache.kafka:kafka-storage-api:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.sourceforge.argparse4j:argparse4j:jar:0.7.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-scala_2.13:jar:2.14.1:test
[INFO]    |  |  \- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.8:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.14.1:test
[INFO]    |  +- net.sf.jopt-simple:jopt-simple:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.bitbucket.b_c:jose4j:jar:0.7.9:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-collection-compat_2.13:jar:2.6.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang.modules:scala-java8-compat_2.13:jar:1.0.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.scala-lang:scala-reflect:jar:2.13.10:test
[INFO]    |  +- com.typesafe.scala-logging:scala-logging_2.13:jar:3.9.4:test
[INFO]    |  +- io.dropwizard.metrics:metrics-core:jar:4.2.15:test
[INFO]    |  \- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.4:test
[INFO]    +- org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:test:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.2.0:test
[INFO]    |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO]    |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO]    \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO]       \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.9.2:test
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

As you can see, all the kafka jar versions are 3.4.0.

And with Boot 2.7.x...

```xml
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>so75458160</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>so75458160</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <kafka.version>3.4.0</kafka.version>
        <spring-kafka.version>2.9.5</spring-kafka.version>
    </properties>
```

Comment: Thanks for the observation, this temporarily solves my issue because I can get past the vulnerability. 
But I will continue to look for a permanent fix to update kafka above 3.2.3.

Comment: I didn't notice that you already had `<kafka.version/>` in your POM. That works fine for me so something else must be causing the mismatch. Try looking at the dependency tree.

Comment: See the edit which shows it working as expected.